# Bootstrap 4 Navbar toggle not display in iPad Pro

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I using BootStrap 4.1.1 .My navbar is not perfect in iPadPro.It show wrong data from div and not colapse.But small devices its working perfect. How to fix it ?

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-default">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
<...content...>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: see here:https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2367

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all. When I change class `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-default">` to `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-inverse">` it working for me.It working on IPad Pro and all Mobile Screen. Thank for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Remove class name **navbar-expand-lg**  and use css **navbar-expand-md**

Comment: I had change to navbar-expand-md but it not work in Ipad